# Carrinho de compras em um mesmo Cookie - Não consigo detectar o erro no código

Tags: php, cookies

Estou testando um carrinho de compras... E estou armazenando os itens do carrinho em um mesmo Cookie, mas
não estou conseguindo detectar o problema. Eu to gravando o carrinho em uma array bidimensional de 3 itens fixos como valor no cookie que são: **nome do produto - quantidade - preço** O problema é que ao clicar num mesmo produto a quantidade é incrementada MAS quando clico em outro produto o produto que tem mais de 1 item comprado (tipo 4 itens do mesmo produto), ZERA. Fazendo um var_dump e olhando o cookie está acontecendo de, em vez de continuar incrementando a quantidade do produto repetido, este mesmo produto vai para um outro valor na array, desconfio que o problema seja no COUNT mas já estou a horas aqui e não consigo resolver, (SE ficar clicando repetidamente no comprar o mesmo produto incrementa MAS ao clicar em comprar um ITEM diferente e voltar ao item repetido, o item repetido zera, MAS ESTÁ lá
no cookie só que com outro indice).... segue o código:

```
<?php
//pegamos o item adicionado ao carrinho//
$produto = $_GET['produto'];
$preco   = $_GET['preco'];

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Procedimento para inserção dos itens do carrinho   //////////
if(!isset($_COOKIE['itens_carrinho'])) {     //Se NÃO existe este COOKIE CRIAMOS //
    
    //Criamos o primeiro COOKIE como primeiro ITEM do CARRINHO//
    //Criamos uma array bidimensional
    $itens_carrinho=[[]];
    //inserimos 1 item com 3 valores na array bidimensional//
    $itens_carrinho[0][0] = $produto; 
    $itens_carrinho[0][1] = 1;
    $itens_carrinho[0][2] = $preco; 
    
    //codificamos o primeiro ITEM do carrinho//
    $itens_carrinho = json_encode($itens_carrinho);
    
    //inserimos o carrinho gravado e ENCODADO dentro do COOKIE
    setcookie('itens_carrinho', $itens_carrinho, time() + 86.400 * 30); 
    
    header('Location: inserido-com-sucesso.php?produto='.$produto.'&preco='.$preco);

} 

if(isset($_COOKIE['itens_carrinho'])) {         //Se EXISTE este COOKIE//
    
    if(!empty($_COOKIE['itens_carrinho'])){     //Se este cookie nao está vazio
    
        //Pegamos o Cookie//
        $itens_carrinho = $_COOKIE['itens_carrinho'];

        //Decodificamos o item_carrinho de STRING para ARRAY novamente//
        $itens_carrinho = json_decode($itens_carrinho);
    
        //Verificamos quantos itens tem no carrinho//
                                            //NOTA: O ERRO PODE ESTAR AQUI//
        $itens = count($itens_carrinho);    // com count o valor sempre é um a mais, pois não conta o 0//          
        
        //Nome do Produto vindo de $_GET//
        $nome_do_item = $produto;
        
        //Verificamos SE este PRODUTO já EXISTE no carrinho //NOTA: O ERRO PODE ESTAR AQUI//
        for($x=0, $num_itens = $itens; $x < $num_itens; $x++){                                                                     
            if($itens_carrinho[$x][0] == $nome_do_item){
                 //SE já EXISTE este item//
                 //Procedimento de INCREMENTO da quantidade do item EXISTENTE - ATUALIZAÇÃO
                 $itens_carrinho[$x][1] = $itens_carrinho[$x][1] + 1;
                 $page_redirect = 'inserido-novamente-com-sucesso.php?produto='.$produto.'&preco='.$preco.'&quantidade='. $itens_carrinho[$x][1];
                 $existe = 'SIM';
                
            }else{
                 $existe = 'NAO';
            }
        }
        
        
        //Caso NÃO EXISTA este produto no cookie, gravamos um novo usando o COUNT, que é a última posição
        if($existe == 'NAO'){                                       
            //Criamos um NOVO ITEM no ARRAY//
                           //NO ULTIMO PONTO//
            $itens_carrinho[$itens][0] = $produto;
            $itens_carrinho[$itens][1] = 1;
            $itens_carrinho[$itens][2] = $preco;
            
            //codificamos o NOVO ITEM do carrinho//
            $itens_carrinho = json_encode($itens_carrinho); 
            //Gravamos o NOVO ITEM CODIFICADO no COOKIE
            setcookie('itens_carrinho', $itens_carrinho, time() + 86.400 * 30); 
            //Redirecionamos para a página inserido-com-sucesso.php
            header('Location:inserido-com-sucesso.php?produto='.$produto.'&preco='.$preco);
            
        //Caso NÃO EXISTA este produto no cookie, gravamos um novamente nele com o ARRAY ATUALIZADO     
        }elseif($existe == 'SIM'){ 
                               
            //codificamos o ARRAY ATUALIZADO//
            $itens_carrinho = json_encode($itens_carrinho);             
            //Gravamos o cookie novamente (ATUALIZAMOS ELE) com os dados ATUALIZADOS
            setcookie('itens_carrinho', $itens_carrinho, time() + 86.400 * 30);
            //Redirecionamos para a página de ATUALIZAÇÃO da quantidade do COOKIE
            header('Location:'. $page_redirect);
        }   
            
    }
}
?>
```

Na imagem abaixo aparece uma outra página dando um var_dump no cookie, e todos estão lá
mas como disse ao clicar em outro produto o que tem (vários tens adicionados) vai para um novo indice.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O Problema pode estar aqui na verdade

```
$itens_carrinho[$itens][0]
```

Porque o itens tem o count do array.

Minha sugestão? O índice do seu array deve ser sempre o cod_produto, porque dessa forma fica mais fácil de você controlar, não precisaria de tanto if.

Outro detalhe, porque escolheu cookie e não session ?

Comment: Olá Augusto,   

Vou tentar aqui a sua sugestão, não fiz com session porque estou treinando com foco em cookies somente.

Answer (score 0):

Achei o erro, no ponto que eu suspeitava....

aqui...

```
 //Verificamos SE este PRODUTO já EXISTE no carrinho //NOTA: O ERRO PODE ESTAR AQUI//
    for($x=0, $num_itens = $itens; $x < $num_itens; $x++){                                                                     
        if($itens_carrinho[$x][0] == $nome_do_item){
             //SE já EXISTE este item//
             //Procedimento de INCREMENTO da quantidade do item EXISTENTE - ATUALIZAÇÃO
             $itens_carrinho[$x][1] = $itens_carrinho[$x][1] + 1;
             $page_redirect = 'inserido-novamente-com-sucesso.php?produto='.$produto.'&preco='.$preco.'&quantidade='. $itens_carrinho[$x][1];
             $existe = 'SIM';
            
        }else{
             $existe = 'NAO';
        }
    }
```

É no loop for, ele ao achar o item repetido não parava(óbvio...rs) e invariavelmente ele
ao percorrer o array a variável $existe pegava o valor NÃO, retirei o trecho:

```
        }else{
             $existe = 'NAO';
        }
    }
```

e coloquei o $existe = 'NÃO' como valor padrão fora do LOOP, que somente muda o valor quando acusa um item repetido e não, não.... e usei o in_array
para achar o valor do produto igual em vez do == reduzindo também à primeira dimensão do array para realizar a busca.

vlws abraço a todos.